# Twitter GET not working with since_id

Tags: r, twitter

Working in R, but that shouldn't really matter.

I want to gather all tweets after : https://twitter.com/ChrisChristie/status/663046613779156996

So Tweet ID : 663046613779156996

```
    base = "https://ontributor_details = "contributor_details=true"
    ## include_rts
    include_rts = "include_rts=true"
    ## exclude_replies
    exclude_replies =         "exclude_replies=false"api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?"
   queryName = "chrischristie"
   query = paste("q=", queryName, sep="")
   secondary_url = paste(query, count,        contributor_details,include_rts,exclude_replies, sep="&") 
   final_url = paste(base, secondary_url, sep="")
   timeline = GET(final_url, sig)
```

This (the above) works.  There is no since_id.  The URL comes out to be

```
   "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?q=chrischristie&count=200&contributor_details=true&include_rts=true&exclude_replies=false"
```

The below does not, just by adding in the following

```
cur_since_id_url = "since_id=663046613779156996"

secondary_url = paste(query, count, 

contributor_details,include_rts,exclude_replies,cur_since_id_url, sep="&")

final_url = paste(base, secondary_url, sep="")

timeline = GET(final_url, sig)
```

The url for the above there is

```
"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?q=chrischristie&count=200&contributor_details=true&include_rts=true&exclude_replies=false&since_id=663046613779156992"
```

Comment: `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=chrischristie&count=10&contributor_details=TRUE&include_rts=TRUE&exclude_replies=FALSE&ince_id=663046613779156992` seems to work here.

Comment: How interesting. So apparently you can use q=name without since_id, but it has to be switched to scree_name=name when you do use it.  This is obviously the appropriate way.  Thanks!

If you post an answer, I'd be happy to accept it since this helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
require(httr)
myapp <- oauth_app(
  "twitter",
   key = "......",
   secret = ".......")
twitter_token <- oauth1.0_token(oauth_endpoints("twitter"), myapp)
req <- GET("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json",
           query = list(
             screen_name="chrischristie",
             count=10,
             contributor_details=TRUE,
             include_rts=TRUE,
             exclude_replies=FALSE,
             since_id=663046613779156992),
           config(token = twitter_token))
content(req)
```

Have a look at [GET statuses/user_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline)